# Salvar estado ao retornar para uma activity

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma activity de cadastro com 4 campos: 1 editText e 3 Spinners.
No clique de um botão os dados preenchidos nesses campos são registrados no banco de dados e levam para uma outra activity com uma imageView de confirmação, que ao passar 2 segundos volta para a activity de cadastro automaticamente.

Neste caso, preciso que ela volte herdando o preenchimento que estava antes do clique do botão, para que o usuário não precise digitar tudo novamente e alterar somente o que ele necessitar. Como posso fazer isso? Eis o clique que eu preciso chamar activity de confirmaçãoo com o imageView:

```
btn_Poliform.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            produto.setMatricula(Integer.parseInt(editText_matricula.getText().toString()));
            produto.setSupervisao(spinner_supervisao.getSelectedItem().toString());
            produto.setMaterial(spinner_material.getSelectedItem().toString());
            produto.setQuantidade(Integer.parseInt(spinner_quantidade.getSelectedItem().toString()));

            if(btn_Poliform.getText().toString().equals("REGISTRAR AGORA")){

                bdHelper.salvarProduto(produto);
                bdHelper.close();
            }

        }
    });
```

Eis a activity de confirmação com o tempo de 2 segundos:

```
public class Finalizando extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_finalizando);

    final int MILISEGUNDOS = 2000;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Finalizando.this, RegistrosMateriais.class);
            Finalizando.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, MILISEGUNDOS);
}
```

Comment: Por que vc fez uma outra activity so para mostrar a tela de finalização, sendo que vc poderia fazer um DialogFragment na mesma acitivity e ainda controlar tudo localmente na activity, nao faz sentido sair criando activity sem ter uma atividade especifica para ela

Comment: Tem razão mas eu não sei fazer um DialogFragment, não sabia nem que existia KKKKK, pode me ajudar? Eu preciso de uma confirmação bem grande pro usuário entender que realmente foi salvo, entende por isso escolhi uma imageView separa logo..

Comment: Vou postar a resposta que vc precisa pra fazer um dialog em tela cheia que parece uma activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de voltar a lançar a Activity RegistrosMateriais, no método `run()`, faça `finish()`.

```
public class Finalizando extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_finalizando);

    final int MILISEGUNDOS = 2000;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    }, MILISEGUNDOS);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Deu certo.. E no caso se eu quisesse apagar 1 campo somente?

Comment: O que quer dizer com "apagar 1 campo somente"?

Comment: Voltar para a activity de cadastro herdando 3 ao invés de 4 campos.

Comment: Se quiser "limpar" algum dos campos já preenchidos faça-o antes de chamar a Activity Finalizando.

Answer (score 1):

Dá pra resolver esse problema de várias formas.
Eu faria usando o `startActivityForResult`.
Quando você der o `startActivity` da activity de confirmação, você passa um bundle pro intent contendo todas as informações preenchidas.

Na activity de cadastro, quando for iniciar a activity de confirmação, você passa os dados preechidos.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("editText1", stringEditText1);
bundle.putBoolean("spinner1", isSpinner1Selected)
bundle.putBoolean("spinner2", isSpinner2Selected)
bundle.putBoolean("spinner3", isSpinner3Selected)
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfirmActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

No término da activity de confirmação, você termina passando o bundle que recebeu

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras());
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

E na activity de cadastro você implementa o callback com o dado retornado na activity de confirmação

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            String editTextString = bundle.getString("editText1");
            boolean isSpinner1Selected = bundle.getBoolean("spinner1");
            boolean isSpinner2Selected = bundle.getBoolean("spinner2");
            boolean isSpinner3Selected = bundle.getBoolean("spinner3");
        }
    }
}
```

E com essas variáveis você pode preencher de novo os dados.

Um exemplo completo da documentação do Android de como usar o startActivityForResult:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html?hl=pt-br

Comment: Onde coloco o iD do meus campos?

Comment: Vc não precisa salvar o id dos seus campos, só o valor que estão neles.
Quando a `onActivityResult` for executada você seta os valores de volta neles.

Comment: Mas esses valores eu não sei, o usuário pode digitar/selecionar qualquer coisa. (coloquei o código). :D

Answer (score 0):

Fazer msg de finalização com dialog e mais viavel do que fazer uma nova activity, segue codigo

```
public class AgradecimentoDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //aqui faz seu dialog ser em tela cheia
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Cria seu image view
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());


//        imageView.setImageResource(recource); basta adicionar sua imagem de agradecimento
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams param = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(param);

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Depois basta mostrar o dialog que na propria activity e finalizar a msm aposta salvar

```
 AgradecimentoDialog dialog = new AgradecimentoDialog();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"dialog");// mostra seu dialog na tela
    final int MILISEGUNDOS = 2000;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    }, MILISEGUNDOS);
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo!